# Can't get module configuration form into modal

Tags: forms, javascript

I'm writing my first Drupal 7 module. I've successfully created the block's html and integrated that with the home page. I've also succeeded in creating a configuration form fo the block.

However, you can only access the configuration form by going to mysite.com/admin/config/content/mymodule and I would much rather have the user be able to access it in the modal that appears when they click the upper-right gear and click "Configure block."

Is there a good way to add my module configuration form to the block configuration?

Comment: I had to embed a custom form into a modal, the way you should go is with ctools,
here is one of the tutorials that help me out. http://drupion.com/blog/10-steps-creating-ctools-modal-window-drupal-7 and yes it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your configuration form using the [hook_block_configure](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7) instead of making it a page. Add your information to the form as you would any normal drupal form api along with your validate and submit functions. You will also need to hook into [hook_block_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_save/7) for save functionality.